# ¿Como quitar los últimos caracteres a todos los elementos en una lista?

Tags: python, array, lista

Por ejemplo tengo una lista:

```
lista = ['123456-715-10-2015'], ['8765432-105-12-2011']
```

El objetivo que tengo es poder quitarle los últimos 10 caracteres, con tal de que quede así:

```
print(listaActualizada)

>> ['123456-7'], ['8765432-1']
```

Comment: `[ elem[:-10] for elem in lista ]`

Comment: @abulafia Añado la asignación: `listaActualizada = [ elem[:-10] for elem in lista ]` . ¿No sería mejor postearlo como respuesta?

Comment: @emi Prefiero esperar a ver si Javier dice algo más, pues tal como tiene la pregunta no queda claro si su `lista` contiene cadenas (como mi comentario supuso) o es una lista de listas (como su sintaxis, aunque incorrecta, sugiere)

Comment: @abulafia hola, gracias por su tiempo, me resultó como lo señala.

Comment: @emi gracias, esa era mi intención!

Comment: Hola @Javier. Ya que finalmente confirmas que la lista era de cadenas, pongo mi comentario en forma de respuesta y lo explico un poco más para que pueda ser útil a otros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que se tenga una lista de cadenas (la sintaxis de la pregunta hace pensar que podría ser una lista de listas, pero el OP ha confirmado en un comentario que era una lista de cadenas), es decir:

```
lista = ['123456-715-10-2015', '8765432-105-12-2011']
```

lo que buscas se puede hacer con una comprensión de listas como la siguiente:

```
listaActualizada = [ elem[:-10] for elem in lista ]
```

### Explicación

La comprensión de listas incluye un bucle que va recorriendo cada elemento de la lista, para evaluar sobre cada elemento la expresión que le indiquemos (en este caso la expresión es `elem[:-10]`) y construye otra lista con los resultados que va obteniendo de esta iteración.

La expresión `elem[:-10]` usa un par de trucos:

- Rodajas. La sintaxis `cadena[inicio:fin]` permite extraer una "rodaja" (*slice*) o subcadena, que incluya los caracteres desde la posición `inicio` (inclusive) hasta `fin` (no incluída). Si se omite `inicio` es como poner 0, por tanto desde el inicio de cadena.
- Índices negativos. Un índice negativo se cuenta desde el final de la cadena.

Por tanto `elem[:-10]` significa "todos los elementos desde el primero, hasta el que está en posición 10 contando desde el final". Esto equivale por tanto a quedarse con todos los caracteres salvo los 10 últimos.